# React Native Flatlist select filter not refreshing

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

react native newbie here. I have an experimental program display values by Flatlist and a Select header at the top. The Flatlist display fine on first load when I try to select values from dropdown the Flastlist doesn't display the current array data.  Any ideas why it's not loading?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {Select, Option} from "react-native-chooser";
import FlatList from 'react-native/Libraries/Lists/FlatList';

import demoData from './data';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Property Listing',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      item: [],
      refreshing: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest({refreshing: false});
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = (data1) => {

    this.setState({refreshing: true});

      const item = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let obb = data[i].location.state;

        if(data1===obb) {
           item.push(data[i]);
        } 
        this.setState({refreshing: false});
      }
      console.log(item);
      return item;

  };

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({refreshing: true},
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };


  renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <Select 
        onSelect = {this.makeRemoteRequest.bind(this)} 
        defaultText  = "Select a State" 
        style={styles.selectWrapper} 
        optionListStyle = {{backgroundColor : "#F5FCFF"}}> 
          <Option value = "Arizona">Arizona</Option>
          <Option value = "California">California</Option>
          <Option value = "New Hampshire">New Hampshire</Option>
        </Select>
    );
  };

  renderItem({item, index }) {
      return(
        <View style={styles.container2}>
          <View><Image source={{ uri: item.picture}} style={styles.photo} /></View>
          <View style={styles.info}>
            <View><Text style={styles.headline}>Address:</Text></View>
            <View><Text style={styles.text}>{`${item.location.street} ${item.location.city} ${item.location.state} ${item.location.postcode}`}</Text></View>
            <View><Text>Bed: {`${item.houseDetails.bed} Bath: ${item.houseDetails.bath} Rent: $${item.houseDetails.monthlyRent}`}</Text></View>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList style={styles.container} data={demoData} renderItem={this.renderItem} ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader} refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}  keyExtractor={item => item.email}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const HomeView = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container2: {
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
    borderColor: '#8E8E8E',
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  },
  selectWrapper: {
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
    borderColor: '#8E8E8E',
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    margin: 10,
    width: 340,
  },
  separator: {
    flex: 1,
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    backgroundColor: '#8E8E8E',
  },
  headline: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign :'left',
  },
  photo: {
    width: 340,
    height: 210,
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
  info: {
    padding: 10,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject3', () => HomeView);
```

I appreciate any ideas, I'm stuck with this for few days. I think I need some help. Thank you!

=== UPDATE JSON DATA FILE ADDED

name of file: data.js

```
export default data = [
  {
    "gender": "Male",
    "name": {
      "title": "Mr",
      "first": "Aiden",
      "last": "Lucas"
    },
    "email": "aiden.lucas@example.com",
    "phone": "(661)-131-8187",
    "cell": "(408)-707-4720",
    "houseDetails": {
      "bed": "1",
      "bath": "1",
      "area": "1100 sqft",
      "monthlyRent": '2800'
    },
    "location": {
      "street": "1446 Oak Lawn Ave",
      "city": "Lakewood",
      "state": "Arizona",
      "postcode": 60649
    },
    "picture": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=37.730064,-122.4245857&size=1280x720&fov=90&key=AIzaSyA5W0tVVAfUcZmObnmWt836xzc4NWob2Z4"
  },
  {
    "gender": "Male",
    "name": {
      "title": "Mr",
      "first": "Mario",
      "last": "Walters"
    },
    "email": "mario.walters@example.com",
    "phone": "(612)-481-1846",
    "cell": "(213)-966-9760",
    "houseDetails": {
      "bed": "2",
      "bath": "1",
      "area": "970 sqft",
      "monthlyRent": '2500'
    },
    "location": {
      "street": "266 Ney St",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "state": "California",
      "postcode": 60649
    },
    "picture": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=37.7379437,-122.3875249&size=1280x720&fov=90&key=AIzaSyA5W0tVVAfUcZmObnmWt836xzc4NWob2Z4"
  },
  {
    "gender": "Male",
    "name": {
      "title": "Mr",
      "first": "Joseph",
      "last": "Lambert"
    },
    "email": "joseph.lambert@example.com",
    "phone": "(481)-952-7376",
    "cell": "(249)-044-4521",
    "houseDetails": {
      "bed": "2",
      "bath": "1",
      "area": "986 sqft",
      "monthlyRent": '3500'
    },
    "location": {
      "street": "2673 W Pecan St",
      "city": "Surrey",
      "state": "New Hampshire",
      "postcode": 12183
    },
    "picture": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=37.7352032,-122.3979859&size=1280x720&fov=90&key=AIzaSyA5W0tVVAfUcZmObnmWt836xzc4NWob2Z4"
  },
  {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "title": "Ms",
      "first": "Tina",
      "last": "Jennings"
    },
    "email": "tina.jennings@example.com",
    "phone": "(938)-316-5866",
    "cell": "(524)-445-7740",
    "houseDetails": {
      "bed": "1",
      "bath": "1",
      "area": "200 sqft",
      "monthlyRent": '1200'
    },
    "location": {
      "street": "600 Los Palmos Dr",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "state": "California",
      "postcode": 60649
    },
    "picture": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=37.7349324,-122.4555814&size=1280x720&fov=90&key=AIzaSyA5W0tVVAfUcZmObnmWt836xzc4NWob2Z4"
  },
];
```

UPDATE--- 
I already figure out how to display the array values. I condition the flatlist below and update the array value by doing set.state

Comment: Where is `data` coming from in your FlatList? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: the data is from json file.. i update the post above,i added the data file content sample

Answer (score 0):

Add "extraData={this.state}" prop to FlatList so that the list itself re-renders on state change.

Comment: i added "extraData={this.state.item}" to Flatlist but still no luck, can you elaborate more the solution? and confirm it's working?

Comment: Please try to provide more info with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This because your FlatList is always pointing to static data. You're not actually updating the data source in `makeRemoteRequest` just returning an array and doing nothing with it. Store your data in a state variable, set the state with your new data and have your FlatList point to this data.

You're also trying to access `data` in `makeRemoteRequest` which isn't defined anywhere.

In your constructor you would initialise your state variable do your static data. Then in `makeRemoteRequest` you would set the state to the new piece of data you have derived `this.setState({ data: newData })`. This would subsequently trigger a render in your FlatList component provided it is pointing to your data state variable.

Comment: ahh, I see.. can you correct my code how to update data in makeremoterequests? still newbie trying to understand the react-native coding style.. Im not sure how to condition the data object from my select option value and store to the new data array and broadcast. can you help me structure out so I can understand more? thank you

Comment: In all honesty I don't think it would benefit you much if I corrected your code. I recommend you read up on React/Native and learn about states, props and component lifecycles so that you have a better understanding of what's going on and can make better decisions. The RN website has plenty of very useful documentation. I've updated my answer with a bit more info.

Comment: Ok thanks, fortunately I already figure it out in a different way.